# Display each child nodes from the XML file to different div in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I want to display product id= " 1" in one div and 2 in the other div below is my xml code.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="product_list.xsl"?>

      <PRODUCTS>
//Here should be where the first child node would be
    <product id = "1">
    <name>Bob Dylan 1</name>
    <product_desc>Ever man are put down his very. And marry may table him avoid. Hard sell it were into it upon.
       He forbade affixed parties of assured to me windows. Happiness him nor she disposing provision.
      State thing might stand one his plate. Offending or extremity therefore so difficult he on provision. Tended depart turned not are. </product_desc>
    </product>
 //Here should be where the second child node would be
     <product id = "2">
    <name>Bob Dylan 2</name>
    <product_desc>Ever man are put down his very. And marry may table him avoid. Hard sell it were into it upon.
       He forbade affixed parties of assured to me windows. Happiness him nor she disposing provision.
      State thing might stand one his plate. Offending or extremity therefore so difficult he on provision. Tended depart turned not are. </product_desc>
    </product>
 //Here should be where the third child node would be
    <product id = "3">
    <name>Bob Dylan 3</name>
    <product_desc>Ever man are put down his very. And marry may table him avoid. Hard sell it were into it upon.
       He forbade affixed parties of assured to me windows. Happiness him nor she disposing provision.
      State thing might stand one his plate. Offending or extremity therefore so difficult he on provision. Tended depart turned not are. </product_desc>
    </product>
 //Here should be where the fourth child node would be
    <product id = "4">
    <name>Bob Dylan 4</name>
    <product_desc>Ever man are put down his very. And marry may table him avoid. Hard sell it were into it upon.
       He forbade affixed parties of assured to me windows. Happiness him nor she disposing provision.
      State thing might stand one his plate. Offending or extremity therefore so difficult he on provision. Tended depart turned not are. </product_desc>
     </product>


     </PRODUCTS>
```

Here is my javascript I used to display XML data to my HTML page but it does it display in different div in the html.

```
      <script>
        function loadXMLDoc(filename)
     {
      if (window.ActiveXObject)
     {
      xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     }
     else
    {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("product_list.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("product_list.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("showProduct").innerHTML = ex;
  document.getElementById("showProduct2").innerHTML = ex;
  document.getElementById("showProduct3").innerHTML = ex;
  document.getElementById("showProduct4").innerHTML = ex;

  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("showProduct").appendChild(resultDocument);
  document.getElementById("showProduct2").appendChild(resultDocument);
  document.getElementById("showProduct3").appendChild(resultDocument);
  document.getElementById("showProduct4").appendChild(resultDocument);

  }
}
</script>
```

Below is the part where I would put my XML data.

```
    <div class="product-container" >
<div class="product-info">
  <div class="product-img" style="max-width:50%">
    <img src="1.jpg"style="max-width:100%">
  </div>
<div id="showProduct"> </div>


<button type="button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Product 2 -->
<div class="product-container" >
<div class="product-info">
  <div class="product-img" style="max-width:50%">
    <img src="1.jpg"style="max-width:100%">
  </div>


<div id='showProduct2'></div>

<button type="button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Product 3 -->
<div class="product-container" >
<div class="product-info">
  <div class="product-img" style="max-width:50%">
    <img src="1.jpg"style="max-width:100%">
  </div>


<div id='showProduct3'></div>

<button type="button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</div>


<!-- Product 4 -->
<div class="product-container" >
<div class="product-info">
  <div class="product-img" style="max-width:50%">
    <img src="1.jpg"style="max-width:100%">
  </div>


<div id='showProduct4'></div>

<button type="button">Add to cart</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Below is my XSLT code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<body style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12pt;background-color:#EEEEEE">

<xsl:for-each select="PRODUCTS/product[1]">
  <div style="background-color:teal;color:white;padding:4px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="product_desc"/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="PRODUCTS/product[2]">
  <div style="background-color:#000000;color:white;padding:4px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="product_desc"/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="PRODUCTS/product[3]">
  <div style="background-color: #FF0000;color:white;padding:4px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="product_desc"/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="PRODUCTS/product[4]">
  <div style="background-color:#FFFF00;color:white;padding:4px">
    <span style="font-weight:bold"><xsl:value-of select="name"/> - </span>
    <xsl:value-of select="product_desc"/>
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>




</body>
</html>
```

The result I was expecting is that product id 1 would be in one div and product id 2 would be in another. but it come out all of the xml data in one div. Anyone knows what's wrong with my code? And how should I change it so it would seperate the XML data. one div one product id XML data. I'm thinking there should be a problem in my javascript.

Comment: Why the mix of XSLT and Javascript, why haven't you simply used XSLT alone to transform the XML to HTML? In any case it is not clear why you expect to be able to run a single XSLT stylesheet once but then get four different results that fit into four different places. Usually, at least with XSLT 1, you have one transformation result for a single transformation.

Comment: As for the Javascript code, DOM nodes inserted with e.g. `appendChild` are usually not cloned but moved if you `appendChild` the same node several times. So calling `appendChild` on the same fragment several times is not inserting 4 fragments.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have tried using XSLT alone to transform but there are just too many things that wouldn't work and I'm not sure why. Is there anything I can change in my javascript code to make it work?

Comment: It is not clear which result your XSLT creates (you haven't shown it) but a single XSLT 1 sheet on a single run will not produce four different fragments so I am not sure what you want to achieve there. If the whole approach is conceptually wrong (or at least unclear) then I don't think there is a code fix in Javascript.

Comment: If you change your toolbox and include for instance Saxon-JS then you have XSLT 2/3 in the browser and can target different elements in the HTML using `xsl:result-document href="#showProduct"`, see http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!development/result-documents.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I have put my XSLT code, I'm trying to produce on a single run each product will be allocated to the same HTML file but different div in HTML.

Comment: As I said, your approach is not going to work, either move (well, it is rather a hard jump into a different technology) to XSLT 2/3 with Saxon-JS where you can target different HTML elements with a single XSLT stylesheet run or redesign the XSLT approach, I would still consider simply having the XSLT generate the whole HTML document, if you can't do that, then change the XSLT to have a parameter and call it often as needed, setting the parameter before each run, to ensure it spits out the data of the product you need.

Comment: @MartinHonnen hi, it is possible if you can show me how to set the parameter before each run in XSLT, thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, read the API documentation of XSLTProcessor https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/XSLT_JS_interface_in_Gecko/Setting_Parameters or see previous examples https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/2019/async-load-transform.js. It is still not clear whether you have a known, fixed number of elements or you expect the code to figure that out.